What does weaker term mean in the definition of BigO
I am reading Computer Science Distilled book and in section 2.2 The Big-O Notation there is a line.

A function with fastest-growing term of $2^n$ or weaker is $O(2^n)$

What does weaker mean here? All, I know it is related to weaker growth of the function, what in this context what does it want to say?
Is it, the negative term in the function like $n^2$ in $2^n - n^2$? Here, lets say $G$ is the growth rate of individual terms $2^n$ and $n^2$, then $G(2^n) > G(n^2)$. Is this what the term want to say that, when in a time complexity function, we have multiple terms, the one which is the strongest and dominant will be only be taken into consideration for BigO (worst case analysis).

I understand "weaker" here simply as "less" i.e. if $f\in O(2^n)$ and $g \leqslant f$, then $g\in O(2^n)$. Generally we have transitivity $f\in O(g) \land  g\in O(h)\Rightarrow f\in O(h)$.

From the same section of the book

A function B is "Weaker" than A means any function B whose growth rate will not be more than the growth rate of function A, for sufficiently large inputs.
See Big O notation

Yes, that I know. What I want to ask is what is weaker doing in the same sentence as fastest-growing? In fact the next line says The weaker function is $O(n^2)$ , that perfectly makes sense, because as compared to $2^n$, $n^2$ is indeed weaker.

@tbhaxor It’s just clumsy wording. Don’t worry about it.

@tbhaxor the phrases group together something like "(a function (with (fastest-growing term) of (2^n or weaker) ) ) is O(2^n)"; is that what you're wondering? Don't forget that each term can be looked at as its own function: you can consider the big-O/weakness of each term and also of the full function.

For the first time Wikipedia definition makes sense to me. Thanks all for your time
